# custom rules are not shown in the dashboard

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm writing a custom rules for java, following the tutorial http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101

I've build the maven project successfully, and moved the jar to the folder /extenstions/plugins/ ,and I restarted the sonar service, but I cannot find out the rule I wrote in the rules page.

I thought about I have the wrong version of the software. I've checked the version I use. sonarqube is 5.3, sonarscanner is 2.5, java version is 1.8, maven version is 3.0.5. I've downloaded the java-plugin-4.1.jar from the website and put it into the folder /extensions/plugins/

Comment: Version 4.1 of the Java plugin is only compatible with version 5.6 of SonarQube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Like Michael said the java-plugin version and the sonarqube version doesn't match very well. I upgraded the sonarqube and mysql, the rule finally come into effect. Thank you Michael.